# How to find the row index of a cell array that matches certain row of cells in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, row, cell

Say I have a cell array

```
CELLARRAY = 
{{[]} {[]} {[1 1 1]} {[]} {[]} {[1 1 1]};

{[]} {[]} {[1 1 1]} {[]} {[]} {[]};

{[]} {[]} {[]} {[]} {[]} {[]}}


A = {{[]} {[]} {[1 1 1]} {[]} {[]} {[]}}
```

Is there a smart way of finding the row index within `CELLARRAY` that matches `A`? and my answer would be 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the fastest way is going to be a for loop through the rows and MATLAB's JIT compiler should be able to optimize that decently.

```
matches = false(1, size(CELLARRAY, 1));

for k = 1:size(CELLARRAY, 1)
    matches(k) = isequal(CELLARRAY(k,:), A);
end

indices = find(matches);
```

Alternately, you could use something like `cellfun` to perform the operation for you but it will likely be slower

```
matches = cellfun(@(x)isequal(x, A), num2cell(CELLARRAY, 2)); 
indices = find(matches)
```